# An interesting inequality involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $a,b,c$  be any three complex numbers lying on or inside the unit circle $|z|= 1.$ Let $|a-b|=r, |b-c|=s, |c-a|=t, $ with $r\leq t,$ then the inequality 
$$r^2s^2+s^2\leq 2r^2+2t^2$$ seems to be true. Whether the circumradius  of the triangle  with vertices $a,b,c$ will help us in proving this?  or is there any other alternative approach?

Comment: A new hypothesis part $r\leq t$ is added.

Comment: This is still wrong. See my answer.

Comment: @user159888 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, even with the assumption that $ r \leq t$, is again wrong.

Take $a=(-1,0)$, $b=(0,1)$ and $c=(0,-1)$.

Then $r=t=\sqrt{2}$ and $s=2$

$$r^2s^2+s^2=2\times 4+4=12$$
$$2r^2+2t^2=2\times2+2\times2=8$$

Also, note that since the module of a complex number is continuous with respect to its coordinates and your inequality is a polynomial in $r,s$ and $t$, even the stronger assumption $r < t$ won't work. For example, you can slightly change $c$ to make $r<t$, while the value of the polynomial $r^2s^2+s^2-2(r^2+t^2)$ won't change much because of continuity. Therefore, the inequality will still remain wrong.

For example, modify $c$ slightly and take it to be $c=(\frac{1}{n},-1)$ for some large $n$.

Comment: s  can take values up to 2!.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am still thinking about what kind the stricter conditions could be imposed on r, s, t to get the inequality!?

Comment: @user159888: well, first tell me why do you think that there must be an inequality of this form at all? Where does your interest in that expression come from?

Answer (score 1):

consider a, b, c on the circle with:

$r,s \to 2$ and $t\to 0$

thus

$r^2s^2+s^2 = 20 \geq  2r^2+2t^2=8$

Comment: You are welcome, If you are ok, you can set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. As it is, not true. But when $r\leq t$ it seems to be true. I added in the hypothesis part.

Comment: @user159888 Sorry I lost your edit, I'll take a look asap. Bye